# Volume of sphere split into eight sections?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, 3d

An orange is sliced into eight equal slices. The total surface area of each slice is $54 \pi.$ Find the volume of each slice.

Comment: I think that this is a rather interesting question.  I would also be interested to know what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also, how are the slices formed?  Are they all sliced longitudinally?  or is the orange sliced with three orthogonal planes?  or something else?

Comment: Note that each slice area consists of 2 semi-circles and one "lune" .. assuming you cut along meridians of an orange idealized as a sphere

Comment: Hey, guys, let's not overthink it. It's an orange. We all know it has segments. If you try to split it into segments, you can get pretty close to eight equal ones. If you cut it any other way, things get pretty messy (and squishy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the radius of the orange is r then the volume of the orange is $$(4/3)\pi r^3$$
 and the volume of  each slice is $$  (1/6)\pi r^3$$

Assuming that the orange has been sliced longitudinally, the total surface area of each slice is the sum of three surfaces.

Two semi circular and a cured one. The total area of the two semi circular surfaces is $\pi r^2.$

The surface of the curved one is $$ (1/8)(4\pi r^2)=(1/2)(\pi r^2)$$

Thus the total surface area of each slice is $$ (3/2)(\pi r^2)$$

Solving       $$ (3/2)(\pi r^2) = 54\pi$$
we come up with $$r=6$$

Thus the volume of each slice is $$36\pi = 113.09733..$$

Comment: I agree with your point but normally that is how we slice an orange in 8 equal parts.

Comment: I added that condition to my solution.

Comment: You rightfully assumed  the obviously intended idea of slicing, but obtained the wrong value of $r$ when solving the last equation.

Comment: I fixed it  right now. Thanks for attention.

Comment: The area of the cut parts will not be $\pi r^2$ for $r$ the radius of the sphere except for the cut that goes through the center.  The circles will be smaller.  This will require the orange be larger than $r=6$ and the thickness of the slices to vary.  I think it will be a mess to solve with this cutting approach.

Comment: I am assuming the most common way of slicing an orange into 8 equal parts. As you mentioned  in other cases we have to deal with more complications.

Answer (score 1):

If the slices are eight [spherical wedges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_wedge), the area of each slice is two semicircles the radius of the sphere plus one eighth of the exterior area of the sphere.  That gives $$\pi r^2 + \frac 18\cdot4\pi r^2=54\pi\\\frac 32r^2=54\\r=6$$
The volume of each is then one eighth of the volume of the sphere
$$V=\frac 18 \cdot \frac 43 \pi r^3=36\pi$$

If the sphere is split into eight octants, the surface area of each is three quarters of a circle of radius $r$ plus one eighth of the surface of the sphere.  That gives $$\frac 34 \pi r^2 + \frac 12 \pi r^2=54\pi\\r^2=\frac {216}5\\r=\frac {6\sqrt{30}}5\approx 6.5723\\V=\frac {216}5\sqrt{\frac 65}\pi \approx 148.67$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach this problem. Again assuming the orange is sliced longitudinally, the area of the lune (that would be the skin of the orange) is given by

$$S_l=2R^2\theta$$

The area of the flat sides, of course, is simply

$$S_s=\pi R^2$$

Thus, the total area of the orange section is

$$S=S_l+S_s=R^2(\pi+2\theta)$$

Now, for 8 slices, $\theta=\pi/4$ so that $S=\frac32\pi R^2=54\pi$, or $R=6$. Then the volume is given by

$$V=\frac18\cdot\frac43\pi R^3=\frac16\pi R^3=36\pi\approx 113.097$$